# How to add text to end file text in language c

Tags: c, file, feof

I have a file in the c language that contains the text i want to add another text to this file without deleting the last text only to add new text at the end of the file

Comment: Take a look at [fopen man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) or a [tutorial on fopen](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file in `a` append mode because standard says

> Opening a file with append mode ('a' as the first character in the
>   mode argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced
>   to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to
>   the fseek function.